# Razor span on multiple lines whitespace problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I found some problem in razor. If span is on one line its ok.
If I have a span on multiple lines and for example @if inserts white characters between the value

How to do it it so that I don't have white characters between the value and I could use @if between span.

This is ok:

```
<span class="my_value">@value.Name</span>
```

Problem with whitespaces

```
  <span class="my_value">
        @value.Name
        @if(true) 
        {
         somethong....
        }
    </span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yu can try to use a C# variable with the value in `<span></span>`:

```
@{
    var text = value.Name;
} 
<span class="my_value">
    @if (true)
    {
        text+="ssss";
    }
    @text
</span>
```